# android pageview or fragments for UI controls

Tags: android, android-fragments, pageviews

I'd like to develop an app with a similar interface as below

https://youtu.be/lEiCk4Pre6Y

I believe it uses pageview and fragments.

I came across this link which looks similar, but I wonder if anyone can point me how on the right direction. In other words, what UI controls I should use precisely.

https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Note that it scrolls nicely with the touch screen and it shows another UI on the back. It is not just animation of fragments.

any hints are greatly appreciated.

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a CoordinatorLayout with an AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout making use of either NestedScrollViews or RecyclerViews will achieve a result similar to what's in the video.

Check these links for reference:

[AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html)

[CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

[CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)

[A nice tutorial on the subject](http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/27/coordinator-layout-appbarlayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-viewpager-drawerlayout-navigationview-design-support-library/)